Track User in Change Data Capture Tables
I'm trying to create a trigger that will log the user who made modifications (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) to a table into a Change Data Capture (CDC) table in SQL Server.
Specifically, I want to insert the user (captured using SYSTEM_USER) into a custom field in the CDC table whenever a change is made. I understand that CDC tracks changes automatically, but I also need to capture the SYSTEM_USER along with the change for auditing purposes.
I’ve tried creating a trigger, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. My goal is to ensure that every change to the table is logged with the user who made the modification. However, my current implementation isn't functioning correctly.
Here's the trigger I’ve written (for adventureworks2022 db):
USE [AdventureWorks2022]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_DatabaseLog]
ON [dbo].[DatabaseLog]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserName NVARCHAR(100);
    SET @UserName = SYSTEM_USER; 

    -- Insert audit log for INSERT operations
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [cdc].[dbo_DatabaseLog_CT] (ChangeBy)
        SELECT 
            @UserName
            (SELECT * FROM inserted );
    END
END;
GO


So what exactly does not work? Error messages, or what?

Your syntax looks wrong. Why not just add another column to main table instead of this
